# Auto serialize JSON to correct object type

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have an extension method to serialize a json string to an object

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserialize JSON formatted string to an object of a specified type
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Object type to deserialize</typeparam>
/// <param name="sJSON">JSON formatted string to deserialize</param>
/// <returns>Returns an instance of an object</returns>
public static T FromJSON<T>(this string sJSON) where T : new()
{
    T oValue;

    using (System.IO.MemoryStream strJSON = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter swJSON = new System.IO.StreamWriter(strJSON))
        {
            swJSON.Write(sJSON);
            swJSON.Flush();

            strJSON.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);

            System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
            oValue = (T)ser.ReadObject(strJSON);

            return oValue;
        }
    }
}
```

I have several classes defined to represent the objects I want to deserialize a JSON string to:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a record and it's properties
/// </summary>
[DataContract]
public class Record
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Dictionary of properties for the record
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "properties")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Properties { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Comments
{        
    [DataMember(Name = "Comment")]
    public CommentItem[] CommentCollection { get; set; }

    public static Comments FromJSON(string sJSON)
    {
        return sJSON.FromJSON<Comments>();
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class CommentItem
{
    [DataMember(Name = "CommentId")]
    public string CommentId {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Name = "CommentBody")]
    public string CommentBody { get; set; }
}
```

Just a note that I use a Dictionary property because the vendors REST API I am consuming doesn't have a strict set of properties I can code to.

I have a JSON string returned from the REST API as follows:

```
{
    "properties" : {    
       "Id" : "12644",
       "Description" : "Test",  
       "Comments" : "{\"Comment\":[{\"CommentId\":\"cfe6235f-40ee-421d-807f-30315a9f1e08\",\"CommentBody\":\"Test 123\"},{\"CommentId\":\"8d89eef6577e22762650ee5225eb9402ca2f\","CommentBody\":\"Test XYZ\"}]}"
    }
}
```

Note that the Comments property contains an escaped JSON string, it's basically a JSON string within a JSON string.

So now that I have an extension method for deserialization and an object model, I can deserialize:

```
Record r = sMyJSON.FromJSON<Record>();
Comments c = r.Properties["Comments"].ToString().FromJSON<Comments>();
```

As you can see, it's a two step process, and I need to deserialize the comment property item by specifying the Comment class type explicitely.

Is there any way to get the deserializer to intelligently deserialize items in the Properties collection to the appropriate class types during the first step?  So even though Record.Properties is Dictionary the object would, in this case be an instance of Comments?

I have tried this by specifying known types in the JSON serializer:

```
...
    DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T), new DataContractJsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        UseSimpleDictionaryFormat = true,
        KnownTypes = new Type[] 
        { 
            typeof(ObjectModel.Comments),
            typeof(string[]),
            typeof(List<string>),
            typeof(int[]),
            typeof(List<int>)
        }
    });
    return (T)ser.ReadObject(strJSON);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but here is how I serialize and deserialize custom classes using json.net:

```
public class AssignmentHistory
{
    public DateTime WeekOfAssignment { get; set; }
    public int TalkType { get; set; } 
    public int StudentID_FK { get; set; }
    public int AssistantID_FK { get; set; }
    public int CounselPoint { get; set; }
    public bool HasBeenEmailed { get; set; }
    public bool SlipHasBeenPrinted { get; set; }        
}

public static string ASSIGNMENT_TYPES_FILENAME = @"C:\AYttFMApp\AYttFMScheduler\AssignmentTypes.json";
. . .
public static List<AssignmentHistory> AssignmentHistList;
. . .
public static void SerializeAssignmentHistFile(string fileStorageLoc) 
{
    var jsonAssignmentHist = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AssignmentHistList); //_assignmentHistList);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fileStorageLoc, jsonAssignmentHist);
}

public static List<AssignmentHistory> DeserializeAssignmentHistFile()
{
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME))
    {
        var assignmentFile = 
System.IO.File.Create(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME);
        assignmentFile.Close();
        return null;
    }

    var assignmentHistFile = 
System.IO.File.ReadAllText(ASSIGNMENT_HISTORY_FILENAME);
    var assignmentHistDeserialized = 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AssignmentHistory>>(assignmentHistFile);

    if (null != assignmentHistDeserialized) return 
assignmentHistDeserialized;

    var assignmentHistoryList = new List<AssignmentHistory>();
    return assignmentHistoryList;
}
```

Comment: It looks in your case that you know at design time all the properties and types of the object.  In my case my json object will contain dynamic properties so I  can't explicitly code the property names or their types in the class.